# Silex routing .htaccess webroot

Tags: php, .htaccess, routes, silex

I'm using the Silex "micro-framework" for routing purposes of my application.
I'm currently stuck on how to rewrite the url with .htaccess.

Standard Silex url: `localhost/myapp/web/index.php/hello/name`

I want it to look like: `localhost/myapp/hello/name`

With the following .htaccess code, I'm able to omit the `/index.php/` part. But I still have to use the `/web/` part.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /myapp/web/index.php/
RewriteRule ^/myapp/web/index.php/(.*) /myapp/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/myapp/web/index.php/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myapp/web/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: I am stuck into the same issue. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

I've faced the same problem right now and the solution was to change .htaccess content to:

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

So in your case it would be

```
FallbackResource /web/index.php
```

This worked for me and I hope someone will find it useful.

Comment: Well, only for Apache >=2.2.16

Answer (score 1):

From: http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/web_servers.html

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /web
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The right would be to set up your `DocumentRoot` to `/path/to/your/app/web`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^myapp/web/index.php/  /myapp/                 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^myapp/                /myapp/web/index.php/   [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, solved with the following

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options -MultiViews
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /web
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)? index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
 RewriteRule ^/?$ /web/ [R=301]
</IfModule>
```